# Matlab: Determinant of VarianceCovariance matrix

Tags: matlab, correlation, matrix-inverse, determinants, fminsearch

When solving the log likelihood expression for autoregressive models, I cam across the variance covariance matrix `Tau` given under slide 9 [Parameter estimation of time series tutorial](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/153-fall2010/lectures/11.pdf). Now, in order to use

```
fminsearch
```

to maximize the likelihood function expression, I need to express the likelihood function where the variance covariance matrix arises. Can somebody please show with an example how I can implement `(determinant of Gamma)^-1/2` ? Any other example apart from autoregressive model will also do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `sqrt(det(Gamma))` for the sqrt-determinant and `inv(Gamma)` for inverse?

But if you do not want to implement it yourself you can look at [yulewalkerarestimator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/yulewalkerarestimator.html)

---

UPD: For estimation of [autocovariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation_matrix) use [xcov](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/xcov.html)

also, this topic is a bit more explained [here](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/ifi/INF4480/v10/undervisningsmateriale/spII_stocastic_processesIII_handout.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the commands which was par of my problem. My other concern was how do I form the elements of the Gamma matrix?